# Filtering through API with React and Axios

Tags: reactjs, axios

I am doing a project that wants me to filter an API based on location. This filter is triggered by 5 buttons, all with different locations. To accomplish this, my plan was to create a storing part of the API's url, and concatenate it with the value of the button that was pressed. for example:

```
const url = 'https://www.my-example-api.com/api/json/filter.php?i=';
return axios.get(`${url}${selectedLocation}`)
```

I am able to call my API and display everything without a problem when I physically set selectedLocation. the only issue I'm running into is calling the value of the button that was pressed to the API file. I have a variable holding the value of the button that has been pressed, but I can't figure out how to send that to the api file.

here an example of how I have the location stored currently:

```
const [location, setLocation] = useState('');
const onClickhandler = (e) => {
      setLocation(e.target.value);
 };
return (
      <button value="Canada" onClick={onClickHandler}>CANADA</button>
 )
```

if anyone could point me in the right direction that would be amazing and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the result with `useEffect` trigger when state changes

```
const [location, setLocation] = useState('');

useEffect(() => {
    //Here do your api call
},[location])

const onClickhandler = (e) => {
      setLocation(e.target.value);
 };
return (
      <button value="Canada" onClick={onClickHandler}>CANADA</button>
 )
```

Comment: why would you use an `useEffect` instead of directly calling the API in the `onClickhandler.`

Comment: It depends on the request of the application and components, of course you can call it with just function too @mariusflorescu

Comment: @Evren I see how the useEffect will trigger when the state changes now, but how would I be able to change the selectedLocation variable to change the url that is being fetched?

Comment: Instead of selectedLocation you will put directly state inside so it will be axios.get(`${url}${location}`) @Tubby_Noah

Comment: @Evren perfect I got it thank you very much man this makes so much sense now.

Comment: If it solved your problem, could you please choose it as accepted answer? You are welcome :) @Tubby_Noah